# Data binding of ViewModel to Razor View then get POST ViewModel to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

**UPDATED POST**

I am currently developing a Survey application that uses MVC4, Razor, EF5. There will be various surveys an will be utilizing one view. The Models for the application comes from an existing database. Apart from that, I created a separate Entities for the following:

**SurveyDisplay** - Model for elements that will appear on the survey page because it consists of different languages.

**SurveyInfo** - Model for information where data comes from a web service.

**SurveyQuestion** - Model for the questionnaires of the survey.

**SurveyChoices** - Model for the choices of each question in the survey.

**SurveyAnswers** - Model to retrieve choices of answers

**UPDATE IMAGE**(Added SurveyAnswers)

Kindly refer to the image below for the following fields:
[image]

I am able to get the particular values to display in my page which is a Razor, but upon POST. I am getting ModelState.IsValid == false. All models are null except for SurveyAnswers.

[image]

[image]

Here's how my code goes so far:

**SurveyRepository:**
For this part, I imported stored procedures to get data from the database.

```
    public List<SurveyQuestion> GetQuestions(int surveyid)
    {
        using (var ctx = new ICSDBContext())
        {
            return ctx.GetSurveyQuestions(surveyid).ToList<SurveyQuestion>();
        }
    }
    public List<SurveyChoice> GetChoices(int surveyid)
    {
        using (var ctx = new ICSDBContext())
        {
            return ctx.GetSurveyChoices(surveyid).ToList<SurveyChoice>();
        }
    }
    public List<SurveyDisplay> GetSurveyDisplay(int surveyid)
    {
        using (var ctx = new ICSDBContext())
        {
            return ctx.GetSurveyDisplay(surveyid).ToList<SurveyDisplay>();
        }
    }
```

**SurveyController:**

```
using ICS.Repositories;
using ICS.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class SurveyController : Controller
{
    SurveyRepository surveyRepository = new SurveyRepository();
    SurveyViewModel surveyViewModel = new SurveyViewModel();

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(int surveyid, string rowid)
    {
        var surveyDisplay = surveyRepository.GetSurveyDisplay(surveyid);
        var surveyQuestions = surveyRepository.GetQuestions(surveyid);
        var surveyChoices = surveyRepository.GetChoices(surveyid);

        string headerText = "";
        string messageBody = "";
        string buttonText = "";

        foreach (var item in surveyDisplay)
        {
            headerText = item.HeaderText;
            messageBody = item.MessageBody;
            buttonText = item.ButtonText;
        }
            surveyViewModel.HeaderText = Server.HtmlEncode(headerText);
            surveyViewModel.MessageBody = Server.HtmlEncode(messageBody);
            surveyViewModel.Buttontext = Server.HtmlEncode(buttonText);
            surveyViewModel.SurveyQuestions = surveyQuestions;
            surveyViewModel.SurveyChoices = surveyChoices;

        return View("Survey", surveyViewModel); 
    }

//Not the actual code yet. I'm trying to check in this action whether there is POSTed data or none. 
[HttpPost]

}
```

**SurveyViewModel**

```
public class SurveyViewModel
{
    public List<SurveyInfo> SurveyInfo { get; set; }
    public string HeaderText { get; set; }
    public string MessageBody { get; set; }
    public string Buttontext { get; set; }
    public List<SurveyQuestion> SurveyQuestions { get; set; }
    public List<SurveyChoice> SurveyChoices { get; set; }
    public List<SurveyAnser> SurveyAnsers { get; set; }
}
```

**Razor View**

```
<h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HeaderText)</h2>
    <div id="info">
        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MessageBody)</p>
        <div class="margTop20">
            <ul>
                @for (var info = 0; info < Model.SurveyInfo.Count(); info++)
                {
                    <li>
                        <span>Case ID: </span>
                        <b>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SurveyInfo[info].SRNumber)</b>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Description: </span>
                        <b>Others</b>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Problem Category: </span>
                        <b>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SurveyInfo[info].ProblemSubCategory)</b>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Product: </span>
                        <b>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SurveyInfo[info].Product)</b>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Method of Service: </span>
                        <b>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SurveyInfo[info].SupportType)</b>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    @for (var question = 0; question < Model.SurveyQuestions.Count(); question++)
    {
        <div id="@("question" + ConvertNumberToWords.Translate(question))" class="@(Convert.ToBoolean(Model.SurveyQuestions[question].Subquestion) == true ? "subquestion" : "questions")">
            <p>
                <b>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SurveyQuestions[question].TheQuestion)
                </b>
            </p>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SurveyAnswers[question].QuestionID)
            @if (Convert.ToBoolean(Model.SurveyQuestions[question].Mandatory) == true)
            {
                <p><span id="@("errorQuestion" + ConvertNumberToWords.Translate(question))" class="errorMsg">*Please choose your answer</span></p>
            }
            @for (var choice = 0; choice < Model.SurveyChoices.Count(); choice++)
            {
                if (Model.SurveyQuestions[question].QuestionID == Model.SurveyChoices[choice].QuestionID)
                {
                    if (Model.SurveyChoices[choice].isStyleOptBox)
                    {
                        var choicesGroup = (from c in Model.SurveyChoices where c.QuestionID == Model.SurveyQuestions[question].QuestionID select new { c.ChoicesID, c.ChoicesName });
                        @Html.Raw("<ul>")
                        @Html.Raw("<li>")
                        @Html.RadioButtonForSelectList(model => model.SurveyAnswers[question].ChoiceID, new SelectList(choicesGroup, "ChoicesID", "ChoicesName"))
                        @Html.Raw("</li>")
                        @Html.Raw("</ul>")
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (Model.SurveyChoices[choice].isStyleChkBox)
                    {
                        var choicesGroup = (from c in Model.SurveyChoices where c.QuestionID == Model.SurveyQuestions[question].QuestionID select new { c.ChoicesID, c.ChoicesName });
                        @Html.Raw("<ul>")
                        @Html.Raw("<li>")
                        @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.SurveyAnswers[question].ChoiceID, model => choicesGroup, model => model.ChoicesID, model => model.ChoicesName, model => false, Position.Vertical)
                        @Html.Raw("</li>")
                        @Html.Raw("</ul>")
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (Model.SurveyChoices[choice].isStyleCboBox)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                      <div class="margTop20">
                        <p>
                            @*<textarea cols="" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>*@
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.SurveyAnswers[question].Comment, new { rows = "5", cols = "0", @class = "form-control" })
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    }
                }
            }
        </div>
    }
</div>
<input id="hidQuestionCount" type="hidden" value="@Model.SurveyQuestions.Count()" />

<div>
    @*<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#myModal" id="btnSubmit">@Model.Buttontext</a> @Url.Action("Submit", "SaveSurvey", Model)*@
    <input id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="@Model.Buttontext" />
</div>
```

If you will notice, I am using a custom Html Helper to render radio button groups which is RadioButtonSelectListFor which is very handy in this scenario. I am able to bind and get the value of the selected control as you can see in the image below:

[image]

Secondly, I am also using the Html Helper package Hmtl Helper CheckBoxListFor to display group of checkboxes to make multiple selections and submit it. But the problem is, I am getting 1 value among all checkboxes which causes me real pain and headache. When there is 2 or more checkboxes checked, only the first item is being returned, you may refer to the image below:

[image]

For the comments value, I have no problem with it as I can get the values. As seen on the image:

[image]

I also have one problem, I need to bind QuestionID in SurveyAnswers because it is used for reporting purpose.

To sum up, below are my things to achieve:

**OBJECTIVES:**

1. Bind QuestionID to model SurveyAnswers
2. Return all checkboxes value and add it to list SurveyAnswers
3. If possible, make ModelState.IsValid to be true. If not, I won't be validating model to get the list of SurveyAnwsers

I really want to get this thing to work. I have been doing a lot of research just to get it going, but no progress yet. Kindly help me guys! Any inputs/ suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: its because you have properties that are mandatory and are passed null

Comment: I would wrap your entire survey in an `@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller"))` block, this ensures on your data is submitted and posted to the controller. You don't have to worry about handling the onclick event of your submit button

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Can you please cite one instance? Is it because of the binding from Html Helpers?

Comment: what does `surveyData` look like in your post method? Is it populated

Comment: @CSharper Here's how it looked like. http:s1279.photobucket.com/user/ernieball_26/media/Error_zpscb700b3d.png.html ViewModels are still null. ModelState is still invalid. ='(

Comment: @MusicMan I know you have found a solution for above issue.It's better if you can share it with us. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with these lines in your view model:

```
public List<SurveyInfo> SurveyInfo { get; set; }
...
public List<SurveyQuestion> SurveyQuestions { get; set; }
public List<SurveyChoice> SurveyChoices { get; set; }
```

Because you're referencing full entities, presumably each with their own required properties, you need to ensure that each of those required properties is posted back with some value or it invalidates your entire model, because that individual entity is invalid. However, you're not actually *creating* any of these entities, but rather just displaying existing instances. As a result, you should be using a view model for each of these as well. The only thing that should be required at all on your view model or anything referenced by your view model is the actual data you want to collect from the user.

**UPDATE**

This is all about how the model binder works and how it determines if your model is valid or not. It looks at it as if you would want to save this entire thing to a database, as if you had a table that matched up with your view model (even though you don't actually). So, in order for the view model to be "valid", it would have to be able to save everything else on the view model as well (your `SurveyInfo`, `SurveyQuestions` and `SurveyChoices` properties. If there's any required properties on any of those classes, that isn't posted back (which there of course are), then they are invalid, and your view model is invalid as a result. Now, that said, there's conditions. Simply because you attached a list of `SurveyQuestions` doesn't mean that you have to have a list of valid `SurveyQuestion` instances in your POST body to allow the view model to validate. If a list or relationship is `null`, then it is *not* validated (assuming that the list or instance, itself, is not required). So, really where you're going wrong here is in posting back *partial* instances of these things. Because it's ending up with a list of incomplete `SurveyQuestion` instance, it's invalid, whereas if you simply posted nothing back at all, it *would* be valid.

In other words, you can keep the lists as they are, to pull information from as you need it in your view, *but*, you need to attach POST data somewhere else. Create another list property like:

```
public List<SurveyAnswerViewModel> SurveyAnswers { get; set; }
```

And that would be the only thing that you posted to. Then, as long the user fills out the survey correctly as defined in `SurveyAnswerViewModel`, you'd have a valid view model. Just be aware that since you're not posting the other lists back, you have to repopulated them should the view need to be returned back to correct an error.

Comment: I now get your point Chris. I am using SurveyInfo, SurveyQuestions, and SurveyChoices just to get and display data in my view. All I need to be posted back is a list of answers and not the entire thing. Having that said, when a radio button and/or checkbox is checked, how will I be adding it to SurveyAnswers?

Comment: That's what you would bind your fields to, e.g.: `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SurveyAnswers[index].SomeProperty)`

Comment: Copy that Chris! Let me try it and get back to you and let you know what how it turned out. (",)

Comment: Howdy Chris! I've done your suggestion and it yields with my desirable result. However, I do encounter some obstacles that I need to overcome. I edited my post above so you and others can see the changes. May I know your thoughts? Thanks a lot man!